# Get CRC and ACK of CAN Message

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, can-bus

I wanted to ask for the frame details from the CAN Message Format. From the [Wiki - CAN Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#Base_frame_format), we can see that there are ACK Slot and bits and CRC transmitted for a CAN Message. However, I couldn't find a way to get them from Linux Kernel. I tried looking in net/can directory as well. Is the information about CRC and ACK available to Linux kernel?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SocketCAN

Comment: I already know the SocketCAN. But it doesn't give the CRC and ACK bits. I had specifically asked for that in my question.

Comment: That part is handled by CAN Controller. You don't get SOF as well.